# Issue with clear:right; in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having some problems with IE not showing Internet Explorer not working properly when I clear:right;

```
<div style="border-width:1px 0 0 0; border-style:solid; border-color:#ffae00; height:100px; width:450px;">

<div style="border:1px solid #ffae00; height:100px; width:100px; margin:-1px; float:left;"> Image </div>
<div style="float:left; padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:70px;"> Topic </div>
<div style="float:right; padding:35px 30px 0 0; height:45px; width:50px;"> Select </div>
<div style="clear:right; text-align:center; height:20px; width:450px;"> more </div>

</div>
```

This is my code. In chrome my "more" div is right under the 2 rightmost divs right above it, but in IE it seems to just use clear both.

Any ideas?

Comment: what style is clear? Never heard of it

Comment: IE version? they differ quite a lot

Comment: @DominicB-c `clear` is used to keep sides of an element clear from floats. So adding `clear: right` to an element means nothing should float to the right of that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Put all the stuff of  the right into its own div and then used clear:both. As it is in its own div it only effects the 2 right-most divs.

```
<div style="border-width:1px 0 0 0; border-style:solid; border-color:#ffae00; height:100px; width:450px;">

<div style="border:1px solid #ffae00; height:100px; width:100px; margin:-1px; float:left;"> Image </div>

<div style="float:right; height:100px; width:349px;">
<div style="float:left; padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:80px"> Topic </div>
<div style="float:right; padding:35px 30px 0 0; height:45px; width:50px;"> Select </div>
<div style="clear:both; text-align:center; height:20px; width:100%;"> more </div>
</div>


</div>
```